# While loop error while implementing 'strend'

Tags: c, while-loop

I keep getting errors when I run the program I wrote for 'strlen'. (strlen returns 1 when one string appears at the end of another). I guess it's the first while loop that gives the error, because when I put `printf("%c\n", *s);` instead of empty `;`, it just works fine. Is there something wrong with the syntax???

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    int len;
    int dummy;
    while ( *s++ )
        ; // why error???
    while ( *t++ )
        len++;

    for ( ; len>0 ; len--)
    {
        if ( *(s-len) != *(t-len) )
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char one[] = "I 0dont like youa";
    char two[] = "ke youa";
    printf("%d\n", strend(one, two));
}
```

Comment: Initialize `len` with `0`.

Comment: change to `while( *s )++s; for(len=0; *t; ++t)++len;`

Comment: On 64bit for very long "string"s, the code will fail. Better use `size_t` than `int`.

Comment: Also you want to make the function `int strend(const char *, const char *)`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you forgot to initialize len, you should initialize it with 0.

```
int len=0;
```

Secondly use this:

```
while ( *s )
    s++; // s should be incremented only if *s is not 0.
while ( *t )
{
   t++;  //Same issue here.
   len++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all local variable len was not initialized

```
int len;
```

So the function already has undefined behaviour.

Second after the loops

```
while ( *s++ );
while ( *t++ ) len++;
```

the both pointers point to beyond the terminating zeroes of each strings. As result this comparison (along with the for loop itself)

```
if ( *(s-len) != *(t-len) )
```

is not valid.
Indeed let's assume that we have

```
char s[] = { 'a', '\0' };
char t[] = { 'a', '\0' };
```

After the above loops len will be equal to 1 (provided that initially you initialized len with 0 ). At the same time t and s will point to the memory after the terminating zero.  So `*( s - len )` and `*( t - len )` will represent elements `'\0'` and you will compare only these terminating zeroes while the elements with 'a' will not be compared because the condition of the for loop is `len>0`. That means that there will be only one iteration of the loop when len is equal to 1.

A correct function can be written simpler and more clear

```
int strend( const char *s, const char *t )
{
    const char *p = s;
    const char *q = t;

    while ( *s++ );
    while ( *t++ );

    while ( s != p && t != q && *( s - 1 ) == *( t - 1 ) ) --s, --t;

    return t == q;
}
```

If it is unimportant which one string appears at the end of another string then simply substitute this return statement

```
return t == q;
```

for the following one

```
return s == p || t == q;
```

In this case this program

```
//...

int main( void ) {
    char one[] = "I 0dont like youa";
    char two[] = "ke youa";
    printf("%d\n", strend(one, two));
    printf("%d\n", strend(two, one));
}
```

will output

```
1
1
```

While if to use use the first return statement `return t == q;` then the program

```
//...

int main( void ) {
    char one[] = "I 0dont like youa";
    char two[] = "ke youa";
    printf("%d\n", strend(one, two));
    printf("%d\n", strend(two, one));
}
```

will output

```
1
0
```

Comment: thx a lot! But then i dont understand what difference the 'printf' made in my code. It seems to figure out uninitialized len by itself and run the code properly. Do you know the reason??

Comment: @deNsuh I am sorry. I have not understood what you said.

Comment: @deNsuh Take into account that because len is not initialized then the program has undefined behaviour. It means that it can give either the expected result or an unexpected result.

Comment: @deNsuh As I showed in the implemenetion of the function there is no need to introduce variable len.  It makes the code only complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The error should come because of the missing initialization `int len = 0;`. I recommend using `while` always with embraces like this `while { /*your code*/ };`.

Your 1st while loop should be fine anyway. I made some modifications with two separated loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strend(char *s, char *t)
{
    int len  = 0;           // init 0
    int i    = 0,
        j    = 0;

    while (*s++) { i++; }   // get both string lengths
    while (*t++) { j++; }

    if (i > j)              // compare and use shorter one
        len = j;
    else
        len = i;

    len++;                  // offset: start from 1st character
                            // [fix-issue: 2015-06-28 12:41]
    for ( ; len>0 ; len--)
    {
        //printf("%d: \"%c\" \"%c\"\n", len, *(s-len), *(t-len));   // test-out

        if ( *(s-len) != *(t-len) )
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char one[] = "ABCDE";
    char two[] = "CDE";
    printf("test case 1: [%s][%s] %d\n", one, two, strend(one, two));

    two[1] = '_';
    printf("test case 2: [%s][%s] %d\n", one, two, strend(one, two)); 

    two[0] = '?';
    two[1] = 'D';
    printf("test case 3: [%s][%s] %d\n", one, two, strend(one, two)); 

    two[0] = 'C';
    two[2] = '#';
    printf("test case 4: [%s][%s] %d\n", one, two, strend(one, two)); 
}
```

The output goes like this:

```
test case 1: [ABCDE][CDE] 1                                                                                                                                      
test case 2: [ABCDE][C_E] 0                                                                                                                                      
test case 3: [ABCDE][?DE] 0                                                                                                                                      
test case 4: [ABCDE][CD#] 0
```